# Where are manifest resources stored in an ASP.NET app

Tags: asp.net

In the following code, where should my file "somefile.txt" be stored for the GetManifestResourceStream method to retrieve it:

```
var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("somefile.txt")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an embedded resource (right click on a file within your Solution Explorer, choose `Properties` and set its `Build Action` to `Embedded Resource`).

From MSDN:

> A manifest resource is a resource (such as an image file) that is
>   embedded in the assembly at compile time:
>
> [image: Embedded Resource properties]

More on embedded resources: [Microsoft .NET Framework Resource Basics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950960.aspx).

Hope this helps.

Comment: But this is a website and not a desktop app, so what is it being embedded into? There is no assembly.

Comment: @AndroidDev It doesn't matter because CLR (in this case, hosted by IIS) still needs some code to execute which it finds in your website assemblies (`.dll` files).

Comment: @AndroidDev _Assembly_ is a .NET abstraction term, it can refer to an executable, a DLL or even a set of files.